# Hiding a civilization

Tags: technology, space

In my universe, the solar system ( in the 21st century ) is within a "national park" of sorts, designated by an alien version of the UN , preventing it from being tampered with by any entity outside of the park.

The park works in such a way that it prevents entities inside the park from seeing civilizations as close as 100 light-years from the boundary or the park.

what technologies/ mechanisms could they utilize to produce this effect?

Comment: What is the tech level of the people inside the "park"? Are they primitive cave dwellers or are they capable of space flight?

Comment: What exactly are they trying to hide and at what distances?

Comment: As the others have mentioned there is not enough information to answer this question in any objective way.  If you could elaborate on your scenario that would make for a good question.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot see civilizations as close as 100 light-years outside of the park" ? The park has 100 light year radius and civilizations beyond that have to "hide" maybe? What is the tech level of the civilizations outside of the park? I'm assuming more advanced than 21st century humanity?

Comment: Also please reword "cannot see civilizations as close as 100 light-years outside of the park"

Comment: So  you can detect civilizations from the boundary of the park to 100 ly, but from 100ly onward you won't?

Comment: yeah, there would be restricted access to areas within 100 ly of the park to prevent detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty easy.  Since I would expect most of these civilizations to use some form of communication not dependent on normal electromagnetic radiation.

Where these signals are used (say sending TV/radio signals) they are really pretty far out of our range.  Even though our first radio signal is reaching [about 110 ly away and the first tv signal 74](http://zidbits.com/2011/07/how-far-have-radio-signals-traveled-from-earth/) the 'power' has diminished and is lost in the background radiation of the cosmos.  I haven't found it yet, but it is expected that about 20 ly away most of our signals disappear into the noise.

Now this of course leaves someone purposely sending an extra strong signal into the zone with enough juice to reach us.  This would pretty much need a 'white' noise generator to add to the signal and randomize it into incoherence.

If they have these kinds of toys and rules, then they also have FTL travel and communication to be able to enforce such an area.  They might even have two lines of defense, one that searches for illegal signals (on purpose or just misdirected) and the second set to nullify them.

Comment: +1 for the two lines of defense idea!  We can't detect any communications that are being sent on FTL carriers, so anything that we might see has to be moving at light speed or less.  So an outer line to detect the intrusive signals and an inner line to disrupt them before they enter the preserve.  Put the two lines a light minute apart and link them by FTL communications so they can coordinate their work; then spread each line out into a 3d-sphere and the preserve is safe from intrusion.  Great idea!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, hiding may be easier than getting caught. If they stay away from broadcasting and only use directed communications lasers and their exotic particle equivalents. Add to that the difficulty of interpretation, at 100 light years away we would not able to detect them in a meaningful way.

Actually, species with FTL travel don't use radio they send letters. There is no significant chance of detection.